# In order to make the url bookmarkable, sometimes we need long parameters but IE max url length is only about 2000, How to deal with it?

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, gwtp

This is serious problem.

In GWT, making your url bookmarkable is important. Thus we may have a very long parameter in the url, but IE can only handle url length that is about 2000 characters or less.

So a url can work ok in Chrome but when ran under IE it got chopped off & thus will corrupt the parameter.

So, do you have any idea how to deal with it?

Comment: Aside from limiting the content in the URL? This is a fixed limitation of the browser, it isn't something you can change. Can you share what content you have in the browser and why there is so much in your question so that answers can address that instead?

Comment: we need a lot of parammeter for our gwt app for handling the history, if the url length is limited then the GWT history function is also got limited, can we find a solution like storing the url parameter in Database?

Comment: The url length is *not* limited by GWT, IE has the limitation, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A situation like yours sounds like the result of poor design; you're using the wrong tool for the job. The URL is not meant as a place to store data, but rather as an identifier (or a locator) for that data.

Try to store the parameters elsewhere. Where? That depends. On the server: in the session or in a database. On the client: in cookies or in `localStorage`. You mention "history" in the comments—if the IE you're targeting is version 10 or greater, you can even store [state objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method) using the `history` API.

Comment: let imagine this app, u have a page that have lot of checkboxes & users may click 5,10 or more checkboxes randomly, & last time when user visit the page they should be able to see exactly the number checkboxed that was checked. If you store all these checkbox info into DB then u got other problem, each time u check a checkbox then u need to update DB?? or store in cookies but the url is fixed forever? that is also not a best way anyway

Comment: The state objects of the history API seem like the best choice, but if you need to support older IEs, I'd suggest using either the session or some form of client-side storage. You *can* still update some parts in the URL as well, you just shouldn't use it to store data.

Comment: did u misunderstand what i mean? suppose today user select 10 checkboxes & 10 years later if they visit the same url they still can be able to see 10 checkboxed were checked at the exact positions that the user set 10 years ago. There is no way to use session or state objects in the situation like that.

Comment: Ah, that's a bit different. Still, your only option is probably re-evaluating the need to store that data and the possible ways to do it. Of course if you *absolutely have to* store everything in the url, and it's all checkboxes, you could reduce the size by encoding the values in binary and then base64-ing that—but I'd avoid it if at all possible.

Comment: u mean using encoding? can we have a encoding system that can encode 121212_465465_5456456_321513_21231_5341313..... into a very short number like HUFG545? then we just build the encoding system at the client, that is better than storing params in DB?

Comment: You can represent each checkbox as a binary flag. E.g. with eight checkboxes, the first one could be `0b10000000`, the second `0b01000000` and so forth. Then you just combine them to a representation of the full state, ending up with something like `0b11011010`. Combine that with base64 and the 2000 characters will fit the values of some 11000 checkboxes. That should be enough for any application.

Comment: not that simple, each checkbox has an id, & if the paream 121212_465465_5456456_321513_21231_5341313 then it should pic the currect ID & make the correct checkboxes to be checked